# Elegant way to split an array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Given an array of any kind and the wanted number of subarray, i need this output :

```
print([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].splitInSubArrays(into: 3))
// [[0, 3, 6], [1, 4], [2, 5]]
```

Output must contain the correct number of subarrays even if there is not "enough" elements to fill those :

```
print([0, 1, 2].splitInSubArrays(into: 4))
// [[0], [1], [2], []]
```

I have this working implementation for now but is there a better (more elegant) way of achieving this output :

```
extension Array {

    func splitInSubArrays(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {

        var output: [[Element]] = []

        (0..<size).forEach {

            var subArray: [Element] = []

            for elem in stride(from: $0, to: count, by: size) {
                subArray.append(self[elem])
            }

            output.append(subArray)
        }

        return output
    }
}
```

Comment: Do note that all you're doing is: sorting by remainder.  You can actually get these instantly by dividing.  (If relevant, you don't need to actually make the three arrays!)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can replace both loops with a `map()` operation:

```
extension Array {
    func splitInSubArrays(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return (0..<size).map {
            stride(from: $0, to: count, by: size).map { self[$0] }
        }
    }
}
```

The outer `map()` maps each offset to the corresponding array, and the inner `map()` maps the indices to the array elements.

Examples:

```
print([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].splitInSubArrays(into: 3))
// [[0, 3, 6], [1, 4], [2, 5]]

print([0, 1, 2].splitInSubArrays(into: 4))
// [[0], [1], [2], []]
```

Comment: Well done. I was scratching my head trying to figure out what the OP was trying to do, and you came up with a simple, elegant solution. (Voted)

Comment: This is beautiful, so obvious now :)

Comment: @Manel in algorithms, % is your friend  :)

Comment: Hey @Fattie, sorry but what is "%" ? :)

Comment: ah, I just mean "remainder".

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun a generic implementation that would work with strings as well:

```
extension Collection {
    func every(n: Int, start: Int = 0) -> UnfoldSequence<Element,Index> {
        sequence(state: dropFirst(start).startIndex) { index in
            guard index < endIndex else { return nil }
            defer { index = self.index(index, offsetBy: n, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex }
            return self[index]
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    func splitIn(subSequences n: Int) -> [SubSequence] {
        (0..<n).map { .init(every(n: n, start: $0)) }
    }
}
```

---

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].splitIn(subSequences: 3)   // [[0, 3, 6], [1, 4], [2, 5]]
[0, 1, 2].splitIn(subSequences: 4)               // [[0], [1], [2], []]
"0123456".splitIn(subSequences: 3)               // ["036", "14", "25"]
```

Answer (score 6):

## KISS, algorithm-matching approach:

The most intuitive way to do this is dead simple:

- for each index
- get the remainder when dividing by three
- put the number in that array

So it's really nothing more than this:

```
arrays[i%n].append(item i)
```

---

**Example code per @LeoDabus comment below**

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    func moduloishtrancheization(n: Int) -> [SubSequence] {
        var r: [SubSequence] = .init(repeating: .init(), count: n)
        var i = 0
        forEach {
            r[i%n].append($0)
            i += 1
        }
        return r
    }
}
```

That's the whole thing.

Comment: extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
        func splitIn(subSequences n: Int) -> [SubSequence] {
            var result: [SubSequence] = .init(repeating: .init(), count: n)
            var index = 0
            forEach {
                result[index%n].append($0)
                index += 1
            }
            return result
        }
    }

Comment: I'm not sure if this “remainder method” would be more efficient than OP's, Leo's, and my approach which only repeatedly *add* a fixed number to the offsets. But – as you said – it probably does not matter.

Comment: MartinR, regarding efficiency *in Swift* I'm afraid I have all-but no idea of how very complex structures / operations like sequences, subsequences, appending, slicing, striding etc operate in Swift.  So, I have absolutely no clue.

Comment: @Fattie Feel free to edit your question and post it to your answer

Comment: good call @LeoDabus You know, I've often wondered if there's a way to get "that" index when you "$0" idiom (in the example, the clumsy "var i" would disappear and it would be something like `result[$0.magicIndex % n].append ..` )

Comment: Not all collections are indexed by integers. You could get the distance from the startIndex but this wouldn't be as fast as incrementing an integer on each iteration. Another option is to enumerate your collection and get the offset as shown at Cristik answer

Answer (score 5):

'Twould be good to allow it to be used on all sequences.

```swift
stride(from: 0, through: 6, by: 1).splitInSubArrays(into: 3)
```

(Put this into a public extension too, if it's useful across many apps, like the one below is.)

```swift
extension Sequence {
  func splitInSubArrays(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
    enumerated()
      .grouped { $0.offset % size }
      .map { $0.map(\.element) }
  }
}
```

```swift
  /// Group the elements by a transformation into an `Equatable`.
  /// - Note: Similar to `Dictionary(grouping values:)`,
  /// but preserves "key" ordering, and doesn't require hashability.
  func grouped<Equatable: Swift.Equatable>(
    by equatable: (Element) throws -> Equatable
  ) rethrows -> [[Element]] {
    try reduce(into: [(equatable: Equatable, elements: [Element])]()) {
      let equatable = try equatable($1)

      if let index = ( $0.firstIndex { $0.equatable == equatable } ) {
        $0[index].elements.append($1)
      } else {
        $0.append((equatable, [$1]))
      }
    }.map(\.elements)
  }
```

Comment: indeed, you just group by remainder

Comment: Jessy, I may misunderstand, but why would you sort?  In any situation I can think of where you do this, you surely want to maintain the original order seen in the original array?  Sorry if I misunderstand

Comment: The Dictionary initializer is Swift's only built-in grouping algorithm, but although the values will keep their order, the key-value-pairs are unordered.

Comment: "The Dictionary initializer is Swift's only built-in grouping algorithm" got it, thanks .. but .. I'm too stupid to understand: in fact, would the resulting child arrays, have the values in the same order as seen in the original array?  thx  :O

Comment:  Yes, but it's not actually guaranteed. You can go to GitHub and see the algorithm, which does preserve ordering in the value arrays.

Comment: Gotchya.  Thanks for the detail !

Comment: You don't have to sort the dictionary because the keys are known. I.e. after computing `let d = Dictionary(grouping: enumerated()) { $0.offset % size }` you can `return (0..<size).map { d[$0]!.map(\.element) }` – not sure if that would be more efficient or not.

Comment: What MartinR just wrote would seem to be the most elegant way to do it, in, a Swiftish style.  I think.

Comment: Changed to use no Dictionaring.

Comment: You know, I'm not really sure I can support this answer. The "usual way" to do this very simple issue, in any language anywhere, is just `result[i%n].append($0)` as it were - as in the code fragment L.Dabus supplied. One is simply "adding to a few sets, based on the remainder".  I would say it seems to me that something like  `result[i%n].append($0)` most clearly expresses that you are, well `result[i%n].append($0)` -ing.  I am slightly disturbed by having to do the complex marshaling to enjoy using the (natty) grouped feature or the language at hand.  So, that's (hic) a thought...cheers

Answer (score 5):

For completeness, here's a `reduce`-based solution that works on all `Collection` types:

```swift
extension Collection {
    func splitInSubArrays(_ size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        enumerated().reduce(into: [[Element]](repeating: [], count: size)) {
            $0[$1.offset % size].append($1.element)
        }
    }
}
```

How the function works: it creates a an empty array of `[Element]` entries, and appends each element of the original array to the corresponding sub-array. We're using here of `reduce` just to carry the result array, to avoid explicitly creating a local variable (though internally `reduce` is doing that for us).

Usage:

```swift
print([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].splitInSubArrays(3)) // [[0, 3, 6], [1, 4], [2, 5]]
print([0, 1, 2].splitInSubArrays(4))             // [[0], [1], [2], []]
print("ABCDEF".splitInSubArrays(3))              // ["A", "D"], ["B", "E"], ["C", "F"]]
```

Note that, as Leo Dabus pointed out, in the last example above the 2-D array is not a string-based one, it's a 2-D character array `[[Character]]`. To generate a array of substrings instead, `RangeReplaceableCollection` can be extended, and the result type can be changed to `[SubSequence]`.

Comment: This is exactly what has been suggested by Fattie

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't know how to reply to this, are you implying I plagiarised other's answer?

Comment: I just said he did not provided the code but suggested this approach

Comment: ( @Cristik - I'm pretty sure L.D. was just noting "Ah, this is the algorithm Fattie mentioned. )  Please note that it is the overwhelmingly common way to do this (you often see it in game-related code for example )

Comment: @Fattie depending on the drinks :)

Comment: Note that this would return an array of characters instead os strings in the 3rd example

Comment: On a serious note, not that anyone ever listens to me but I would like to point out again that very often you very simply *don't bother putting the items in arrays* when you do this.  If you're trancheing/numbering the blades of grass so that Lara Croft can mow them down or whatever, you can instantly/trivially do so maintaining the ordering, with the "/%" values instead of bothering w/ arrays.

Comment: You can implement a generic version of this extending RangeReplaceableCollection.

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't see how a more specific protocol would help here. Not that it's doesn't exist, I just don't see it :)

Comment: `extension RangeReplaceableCollection {` `func splitInSubSequence(_ size: Int) -> [SubSequence] {` `enumerated().reduce(into: [SubSequence](repeating: .init(), count: size)) {` `$0[$1.offset % size].append($1.element)` `}` `}` `}`

Comment: @LeoDabus this would help with code size, but would not help many other types that are just collections. Actually, I could simply write `enumerated().reduce(into: [[Element]](repeating: .init(), count: size)) {` on my code, and get fewer characters than yours :)

Comment: @Cristik You did not understand my point. The result of a string should be an array of substrings not an array of [Character] --> ["AD", "BE", "CF"] instead of [["A", "D"], ["B", "E"], ["C", "F"]]

Comment: If you are only interested in reducing code Swift is a type inferred language `.init(repeating: [], count: size)`

Comment: @LeoDabus I see your point now, added a note in my answer about this.

Comment: @Cristik The diference is that `RangeReplaceableCollection` requires an empty initializer. Thats what you need to use to initialize an empty collection like an empty string. Thats why I used `.init()` instead of `[]`. So you would need to change `.init(repeating: [], count: size)` to `.init(repeating: .init(), count: size)`as well and the return type when extending it.

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, I got all those, I know a few things about the Collection family of protocols :)