# Filter vs For, which one is cheaper to use?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an array of Int **Array(1...10)**. Which I like to make 2 sub-array's of it in names of even and odd! Once I use for loop and make those sub-array's in Just **ONE** looping, and then I can make same array's with filter but in **TWO** looping. I like the way filter works, but because it done the job in 2 looping is kind of Not good, in the other hand I like the old fashioned for-loop because of finishing the job in one loop, but as you know it does not have possibilities of filter. So how can decide which is better in this case? can we make filter make those sub-array's in one looping?

code:

```
import SwiftUI

let customArray: [Int] = Array(1...10)

var evenArrayV1: [Int] = [Int]()
var oddArrayV1: [Int] = [Int]()

var evenArrayV2: [Int] = customArray.filter({ $0.isMultiple(of: 2) })
var oddArrayV2: [Int] = customArray.filter({ !($0.isMultiple(of: 2)) })

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
 
        Button("show V1") {

            for item in customArray {
                
                if item.isMultiple(of: 2) { evenArrayV1.append(item) }
                else { oddArrayV1.append(item) }
                
            }

            print(customArray)
            print(evenArrayV1)
            print(oddArrayV1)
            
        }.padding()

        Button("show V2") {
            
            print(customArray)
            print(evenArrayV2)
            print(oddArrayV2)
            
        }.padding()

        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already answer you're question.
if you do this split by filter its take more time because every item in array will be checked. I recommend u to read about "Time complexity".
imagine that you have an array of a million or more elements, which means that when using the filter, the processor will go through 2 million operations, and the usual run is only 1 million. and if the condition is more complicated then you can square the number of operations
so the best way in this case will be

```
customArray.forEach{$0 % 2 == 0 ? evenArrayV1.append($0) : oddArrayV1.append($0)}
```

and be like swift, use forEach instead of forin

Comment: I have nothing to tell unless fantastic! you killed 2 bird with 1 stone! thanks

Comment: there is a method called `isMultiple(of:)` exactly for this purpose

Comment: @mimi your implementation is fine.

Comment: I mean the V1 using the for loop

Comment: yes and if you are dealing with a range you can check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/64933510/2303865 and use `Array(1...10).splitIn(subSequences: 2) `  // [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]]

Comment: Lev, I disagree. Both of the OPs proposed solutions scale linearly. Filtering twice will always take twice as long as a single for loop, regardless of the number of operations. "The condition" will never "be more complicated". This will never have n² complexity, or any other non-linear complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to look at the assembler to be sure, but I imagine that a `filter()` and a `for _ in` take the same amount of time. Thus, 2 filter passes would take twice as long as one for loop that builds 2 arrays. (So `O(n)` vs `O(2n)`.) That said, constant multipliers like that are ignored when evaluating time complexity. Unless your data sets are HUGE, the difference is likely to be undetectable, so you should use the form that is easiest to read and maintain.

Comment: thanks, So I should chose between **syntactic sugar** or performance of my app, i.e. if I am facing with massive data, then I should go for O1, but if data is not a factor in app, then I should probably go for syntactic sugar. can I assume that is a right and logical decide?

Comment: Yup. Unless you're processing hundreds of thousands of records, don't worry about the difference in performance. Pick the approach where the code is easier to understand. (`O(n)` performance vs `O(2n)` is not a big difference. `O(n²)` performance on the other hand will bring even the fastest machine to it's knees with just a few thousand records.)

Comment: thanks I am really interested to know about  O(n²), what it can be a bad programming to bring us O(n²), can you show me 1 or some case to know about this cases and prevent.

Comment: You should indeed read up on complexity. It is an important concept in computer science. Imagine you had to sort an array of objects. Now imagine you use nested loops where the outer loop loops through every object in the array, and the inner loop loops through every object AFTER that object, comparing and swapping when object pairs were out of order. If you were sorting an array of `n` objects, you would do `n²` comparisons. For 100 objects, you'd do 10,000 comparisons. For 1,000 objects, you'd do a million comparisons. For a million objects, you'd do a TRILLION comparisons.

Comment: wow such a bad programming! thanks for information